# How to send location after `create` action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have the following `create` action:

```
def create
  episode = Episode.new(episode_params)
  if episode.save
    render json: episode, status: :created, location: episode
  end
end
```

but when I test the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreatingEpisodesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup { host! 'api.example.com'}

  test 'create episodes' do
    post '/episodes',
      { episode:
          { title: 'Bananas', description: 'Learn about bananas.' }
      }.to_json,
      { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type

    episode = json(response.body)
    assert_equal "/episodes/#{episode[:id]}", response.location
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
1) Error: CreatingEpisodesTest#test_create_episodes: NoMethodError: undefined method `episode_url' for #<API::EpisodesController:0x007f8e34519450> Did you mean?  episode_params
app/controllers/api/episodes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
test/integration/creating_episodes_test.rb:7:in `block in #<class:CreatingEpisodesTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I guest I miss something to send the location after I create the episode.

### UPDATE: Route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
    resources :zombies
    resources :episodes
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be - location: episode_url(episode) ?

Comment: @JovicaŠuša I tried that, but get the same error.

Comment: Do you have corresponding  `show` route and action?

Comment: @Jean `episode_path(episode)` ?

Comment: @Vasfed I justed paste my route on the question.

Comment: @Vasfed same error but this time ..undefined method `episode_path'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of namespace, use `[:api, episode]` for `location`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solve my question, but now I have the following failure: -"http://api.example.com/episodes.980190963"
+"http://api.example.com/episodes/980190963" as you can see the action send me this url http://api.example.com/episodes.980190963 with a dot before the id instead / what can be the problem?

Comment: @Jean `location` is passed to `url_for` as-is, looks like it generates a route to index action with record id in `:format` place. If polymorphic route does not work for some reason - you can pass hash or even a ready url - `api_episode_url(episode)`